# Devise + Polymorphic not making association with :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm working on one of my first apps and Devise is giving me a bit of a problem. I have Devise on one model User that has a polymorphic association to 3 other models Artist, Label, Fan. Everything is wired up correct but when I create for example a new Artist, that all works fine. When I sign back in with that artist if for example the User_id is 2 and the Artist_id is 4, I'll get a "Couldn't find Artist with 'id'=2" on the Show Action in the Artists controller. I have edited the after_sign_in_path_for method to detect the account type to redirect to the right path for type of user after log in, from the log it looks like the show action for Artists is trying to match the User_id and not matching the Artist_id for the logged in user.

My Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  belongs_to :account, polymorphic: true
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_name 
end


class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :account, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tracks, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
  validates_uniqueness_of :artist_name 
  has_attached_file :avatar, 
                    :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "64x64>" }, 
                    :default_url => "https://s3-us-west-    2.amazonaws.com/trackfilter/default/default_250.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end

class Fan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :account, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
  has_attached_file :avatar, 
                    :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "150x150>" }, 
                    :default_url => "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/trackfilter/default/default_250.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end

class Label < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :account, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
  validates_uniqueness_of :label_name 
  has_attached_file :avatar, 
                    :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "150x150>" }, 
                    :default_url => "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/trackfilter/default/default_250.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

 def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
   if current_user.account_type == "Artist" 
     artist_path(resource)
   elsif current_user.account_type ==  "Label"
     label_path(resource)
   else current_user.account_type == "Fan"
     fan_path(resource)
   end
 end
end
```

Artist Controller:

```
class ArtistsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index, :show]
 before_action :set_artist, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 def show
   @artist = Artist.find(params[:id])
   @tracks = @artist.tracks.all
 end
```

Log:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-10 16:19:23 -0600
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"bdHPGqkUlW2OkJiP0qHaJOI1fnEMR3o+wZEwrWoQVxs=", "user"=>    {"email"=>"dino@dino.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'dino@dino.com'  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 (0.1ms)  begin transaction SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "current_sign_in_at" = ?, "last_sign_in_at" = ?, "sign_in_count" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = 2  [["current_sign_in_at", "2014-07-10 22:19:23.660435"], ["last_sign_in_at", "2014-07-10 22:15:59.573569"], ["sign_in_count", 26], ["updated_at", "2014-07-10 22:19:23.661056"]](4.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/artists/2
Completed 302 Found in 78ms (ActiveRecord: 4.6ms)

Started GET "/artists/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-10 16:19:23 -0600
Processing by ArtistsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  Artist Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "artists".* FROM "artists"  WHERE "artists"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Artist with 'id'=2:
```

So clearly to me it's getting the Devise User ID passed instead of the Artist ID.. any thoughts on how to remedy this?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the redirect, you need to give the account as it is the account id that is needed by your artist/fan_controller to find objects.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

 def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
   if resource.account_type == "Artist" 
     artist_path(resource.account)
   elsif resource.account_type ==  "Label"
     label_path(resource.account)
   else resource.account_type == "Fan"
     fan_path(resource.account)
   end
 end
end
```

or better (same logic, different writing):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

 def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
   account = resource.account
   case account
     when 'Artist' then artist_path(account)
     when 'Label' then label_path(account)
     when 'Fan' then fan_path(account)
     else
       #Handle error
   end
 end
end
```

or even more funky / flexible / dangerous:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

 def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
   self.public_send("#{resource.account_type.to_s.downcase.underscore}_path".to_sym, resource.account)
 end
end
```

Comment: ah yes that makes sense.. I knew that was the issue, but I couldn't figure out how to make that transfer.. I'm still having issue wrapping my head around pulling the needed info in the right places.. thanks, this works as you said it would.. haven't tried the dangerous option tho ;)